# How can I keep Customize value menus from running too long to select?

Tags: customize

I've been trying to set `org-babel-load-languages` using Customize in Cocoa Emacs 24.4 (and using Emacs in a text console).

When I click `INS` then `Choice: Value Menu`, I get a `widget-choose` buffer with a list of choices that looks like this:

```
0 = Awk
1 = C 
2 = R
3 = Asymptote
4 = Calc
5 = Clojure
```

etc. etc. all the way to the bottom of that buffer, and beyond.

I can't see either of the languages I'd like to choose (Python and Ruby), so I can't figure out the corresponding letter to press to pick one of them. When I try to click in that buffer to scroll, it closes and pops me back into the Customize buffer. Same with attempts to switch into it with `C-o` and scroll that way.

I've worked around it by setting a choice, saving, then editing my Customize-set variables to suit, but that's annoying.

Is there any way to compel better behavior from that `widget-choose` buffer?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Unless someone has a better idea, consider reporting it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `scroll-other-window` to scroll the window up. By the default the command is bound to <kbd>C-M-v</kbd>. However it seems customize UI does not recognize the complementary command `scroll-other-window-down` to scroll window down. You can work around this by using a negative prefix argument with the command `scroll-other-window` i.e. <kbd>M--</kbd><kbd>C-M-v</kbd>